# C# parameter forwarding

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner, so please bear with me.

This is all C#.

In the class "MainWindow" I have the following code:

```
private void textBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    view.passwordInputEnter(/**/);
}
```

In the class "view" I have the following code:

```
public void passwordInputEnter(object sender)
{
    if (/**/ == "Passwort")
    {
        /**/ = string.Empty;
        /**/ = '*';
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is this: In the class "MainWindow" were multiple methods that would all call a different method from "view" which all did the exact same thing. I want to change that so that they can all call the same method and so that I can easily add or remove them. To do that, I need to identify and access various parameters of the object that started the event. However, I couldn't figure out how I can send

```
object sender
```

that is received by textBox_Enter on to passwordInputEnter(). In that method, I'd then like to call functions such as "sender.Text".

I seriously don't know how to word it more understandable...

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this some kind of Model View Presenter that you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if all the callers of your method are TextBox

change it to

```
public void passwordInputEnter(TextBox textBox)
{
    if (textBox.Text == "Passwort")
     {
         xxx= string.Empty;
         /**/ = '*';
      }
}
```

to call it

```
private void textBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   view.passwordInputEnter((TextBox)sender);
}
```

**EDIT**

But it would be easier to just share the same event for all your textboxes in this case...

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do this (although I must say that's generally not a good practice is):

```
var textBoxSender = sender as TextBox;

if (textBoxSender != null)
{
   textBoxSender.Text = "Changed value";
}
```

Comment: what's a better practice?

Comment: It's not a bad practice as long as you're not handling different types of objects in the same event handler. That is, you always check if it's a TextBox as that event handler only handle things for textbox... don't reuse event handlers for different objects (generally speaking).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly you are asking how pass a parameter to your passwordInputEnter method. Pass the sender like this:

```
private void textBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    view.passwordInputEnter(sender);
}

public void passwordInputEnter(object sender)
{
    if (sender is TextBox)
    {
       TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
       if (textBox.Text == "Passwort")
       {
            /**/ = string.Empty;
            /**/ = '*';
       }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast your sender as follows : 
 var textBox = sender as TextBox

check if it is null, if not then set the Text property on it
textBox.Text = "Changed value";